# avoid multiple if-statements when true conditions are rare

Tags: javascript, performance, if-statement, optimization, time-complexity

I want to create a script that compares variables from two different sources.
I need to compare some values a1, a2, ..., an , with some other values b1, b2, ..., bn. I want to know if a1 = b1, a2 = b2, ..., an = bn. If some of them are not equal, I want to know which of them are not equal. These variables are integers and strings. All the pairs have the same possibility to be equal.

I also know that it is extremely rare for these variables to be unequal. In fact, almost 1 pair of variables might be unequal, in 1000 pairs of variables. I will run the script hundrends of times for almost 20 variables each time, so most of the time all pairs will be equal. I was wondering if I can take advantage of that fact somehow.

As a first approach I was thinking something like multiple if-statements. For example:

```
let equal = true;
let issues = [];

if (a1 !== b1){
   equal = false;
   issues.push("a1!=b1");
}

...

if (a20 !== b20){
   equal = false;
   issues.push("a20!=b20");
}
```

As long as most of the times there will be no unequal pairs, I was thinking to cancatinate all a1,..,an variables to a single variable `variableA` and all b1,...,bn to a variable `variableB`. Compare the 2 variables and only if they are unequal, then do the above process. If my data are cleaned (without null, undefined, "", etc.), does it make sense to do something like that? I am not sure if it reduces time and I think that it might be a bad practice.

```
let variableA = a1 + a2 + ... + a20;
let variableB = b1 + b2 + ... + b20;
let equal = true;
let issues = [];

if (variableA !== variableB){
   equal = false;

   if (a1 !== b1){
      issues.push("a1!=b1");
   }

    ...

    if (a20 !== b20){
      issues.push("a20!=b20");
    }
}
```

or instead:

```
if (!((a1===b1) && (a2===b2) && ... && (a20===b20))){ ...
```

I also considered to store my variables in arrays or objects and compare them. Storing them in objects might be better, I think. My script will be written in javascript, though I am mostly intrested in the approach and not the language.

Regardless of the way that they can be compared, is there any way to optimize it knowing that almost all the times my conditions will be false?

Comment: There isn't really going to be a language-independent answer; different languages and different compilers/interpreters may handle similar-looking code very differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there any way to optimize it knowing that almost all the times my conditions will be false?

If that is the case, the runtime will notice and optimize accordingly. There is no reason for you to do so.

In addition, trying to optimize comparisions by concatenating strings is a very bad idea, because concatenation is more expensive than the comparisions you are trying to optimize. In addition, the cost of comparing strings is roughly proportional with their length, so comparing one long string is not faster than comparing many short ones. And repeated comparisons (first the comparing the concatentation, and then the individual strings) is of course slower than looking at each string just once.

All that said, it doesn't even matter unless that function is executed really often: a modern JavaScript runtime can compare about a billion characters per second. Usually, you'll therefore want to optimizer for programmer time rather than runtime performance, by writing clear and easy to understand code.

Answer (score 0):

```
// place variables in 'a' group into ordered array
a_array = [a1, a2, a3, ..., an]

// place variables in 'b' group into ordered array
b_array = [b1, b2, b3, ..., bn]

// compare each item in array storing indexes of items which are not equal
not_equal_indexes = []
for (i = 0; i < a_array.length; i++) {
    not_equal_indexes.push(i) ? a_array[i] != b_array[i] : ""
}
print(not_equal_indexes)
```

you must use a runtime that accepts multi-typed elements in arrays (i.e. a weakly typed language like PHP, Python or Javascript) for this to work.

Otherwise, create an array for each group and each data type available to the elements of each group. The `for` loop configuration should look the same, with slight modification in remembering the original index position of the element or its original variable name, irrespective of where it is placed in the strongly typed array group.